# What is the best resource/guide for understanding new Storyboard feature in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, storyboard, xcode4.2

I can see completely new feature called Storyboard in new Xcode 4.2 Inteface Builder.
Where can I find good guide helping to deeply understand this feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an introductory presentation in [the WWDC 2011 sessions set](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/). These tutorials and overviews are generally a very good introduction to new Apple technologies.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for it there and it seems I overlooked it: Introducing Interface Builder Story Boarding - session 309

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) is a great two part tutorial on storyboarding by Raywenderlich.

Comment: The WWDC 2011 session Adam mentioned is a great as well. I did both.